# regular expression to remove white spaces in a line and extract specific columns

Tags: regex, perl

Perl regular expression to remove white spaces in a line and extract specific columns

my line looks like this:

```
324446  psharma jobA      2       0       435529  0       0       0     435531
```

Here I can split the line with [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function and then save the values in an array with the below command

```
@strings = split(/\s+/);
```

I do not want an extra variable. 
with regular expression I want to extract value in column 1, 2 3, and 10 as `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and `$10`.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to stackexchange.

There's no need for an extra variable:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = '  324446   psharma jobA 2   0 435529 0 0 0 435531     ';

# Remove leading and trailing white space
$line =~ s/^ \s+ | \s+ $//x;
# Split by consecutive white space and keep certain fields:
my ($col1, $col2, $col3, $col10) = (split m/\s+/, $line)[0, 1, 2, 9];

print "1: $col1 2: $col2 3: $col3 10: $col10\n";
```

Output:

```
1: 324446 2: psharma 3: jobA 10: 435531
```

Meaning you really don't need any extra variables, even with `split`. For example, if you only want to pass those fields down to another function your split line would look like this:

```
some_func((split m/\s+/, $line)[0, 1, 2, 9]);
```

Note that I'm assuming that your column number count starts at 1 and not at 0 (meaning your "column 1" is the number "324446" etc.). That's how I named the variables in my example, too.

Comment: If it works then please [click to accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) so that the question will not appear unanswered anymore.